# Jquery Carousel problem

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, carousel, jquery-tabs

I am trying to insert Carousel inside tabs.. so that there is a Slide show inside every tabs.

The first tab Slide show works fine. but the rest of the tabs its acting weird with components missing

Tabify: http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/tabify/

jCarousel: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

[image]

[image]

Link: http://bakasura.in/king/components.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at the css you will see three classes .popular1, .popular2, .popular3 which get placed on the respective ul tags.  It seems this style is done inline so you will need to modify it in your html doc

popular1's width is set at 856px;
popular2 and popular3's width is set at 200px;

If you change popular2 & 3's width to 856px it seems to work

Comment: kmb385: the width for the ul element is being added dynamically by the plugin. when i tried to had code the width to both the classes. it still doest take it :(

Comment: so your adding the classes via css?  try putting it like this .class{width:856px !important;}  Let me know if that works if not we will figure something else out. Be sure to include the ; after important

Comment: it worked.. then suddenly i realised.. like in the first tab it has to have a circular effect.. once the li elements are over.. it becomes blank :(

Comment: !important bumps the weight of the style up in css

Comment: does the url you provided include the fix? so i can test?

Comment: just made a copy of the file so that if other have a diff fix they can look at the original file http://bakasura.in/king/components1.html

Comment: I think there may be a problem because when the page is rendered the two carousel's have a style="display:none;" set.  Therefore jquery can't pick them up and register the carousel. Try registering carasouels 2 & 3 on click instead of on page load.

Comment: i actually tried something like this.. $(".popular2").click(function(){ //code   }) didnt quite happen :(

Comment: guess wat ? i just initialized the tabs after the  carousel.. and no changes all the orginal code works :)

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you found and answer sorry i went missing for a little. I had to take care of something.  Could you post what you changed I'm interested.

Comment: nothing a all.. initialization of the tabify after the carousel set it right.. reordered it... not a single change